# Why isn't my array available for fit_traansform()? What can I do?

Tags: python, arrays, ubuntu

train.txt has 3 columns. First column and second column were kept in A but I can not use it for **fit_transform**. Why?  Please, help me

```
from macpath import split
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
D=[]

vec = DictVectorizer()

with open("train.txt") as f:
    f1=[x.strip() for x in f if x.strip()]
    for x in f1[0:]:
        data=[tuple(x.split())]
        for x in data:
            A.append(x[0]+" "+x[1])
            B.append(x[2])

X=vec.fit_transform(A)
```

[image]

Comment: Please include your code directly in you question and use the appropriate formatting option to render it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change following part
    `A.append(x[0]+" "+x[1])`
with this:

```
A.append({x[0],x[1]: 1 })
```